# How to get Woocomerce categories count

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

Is there a short way to get the number of categories in woocomerce shop homepage and also number of subcategories on category page?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs it

```
$args = array(
    'type'                     => 'product',
    'parent'                   => get_queried_object_id(),
    'orderby'                  => 'term_group',
    'hide_empty'               => true,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'taxonomy'                 => 'product_cat',
    'pad_counts'               => false
);

$cats = get_categories( $args );
print_r(count($cats));
```